# Do the ajax function with facebook

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, facebook

I am writing a code that retrieve data from facebook to my localhost. I get stuck at this problems, hope you can help:

(1) I get the data from this fb page by cURL:

```
<?php
/* ACC INFO */
$EMAIL      = "";
$PASSWORD   = "";
function cURL($url, $header=NULL, $cookie=NULL, $p=NULL)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    if ($p) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
    }
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
// CREATE THE COOKIES
$cookie = null;
$a = cURL("https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1",true,null,"email=$EMAIL&pass=$PASSWORD");
preg_match('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$a,$b);
$c = cURL("https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1",true,$b[1],"email=$EMAIL&pass=$PASSWORD");
preg_match_all('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$c,$d);
for($i=0;$i<count($d[0]);$i++)
    $cookie.=$d[1][$i].";";
/*
CODE BODY
*/
echo cURL("https://www.facebook.com/browse/likes?id=730777097049823",null,$cookie,null);
?>
```

(2) The next thing I want to do is retrieve more liked users.

Facebook have inserted the AJAX code in "See more" button so I tried to use `xmlHTTP` to `GET` data from [this](https://www.facebook.com/ajax/browser/list/likes/?id=730807700380096&actorid=210695369058001&beforetime=0&aftertime=0&start=100) link. But there're nothing (responsexml and responsetext) from this link. I get stuck at here. What can I do now?

Hope you can help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Facebook Graph API:

It does exactly what you want:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/730777097049823/likes?access_token={insert_your_access_token_here}

{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "123", 
      "name": "John Doe"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "234", 
      "name": "Joe Anon"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "345", 
      "name": "Ieat Pizza"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "asdfasdfadsf", 
      "before": "asdfasdfadsf"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, I know that method already. You know what, every facebook users have 2 uid. 
1 - get direct to that user profile by browser. 
2 - need to login (cookie) to access their profile. (either fb graph api)

Example:
1 - www.facebook.com/1719356018
2 - www.facebook.com/4000191939408

2 uid above redirect to just one users. On Facebook Graph API, they prefer the uid in second type.

Comment: The graph API only requires that you have an access token that is able to access whatever it is you want to access. So in the URL I gave, you'd just replace `{insert_your_access_token_here}` with your actual access token.

Comment: No ieatpizza, I have tried all access token types with graph api. From user long-lived access token to app and page access token. They just gave you an "restricted" uid of the users. With "reality" UID you can get more "things" about this user ;)

Comment: If there's more than 25, the API will only return 25 at a time. Use the paging keys at the end -- `paging['cursors']['after']` and `paging['cursors']['before']` to get the rest. I'm assuming that's what you mean by 'restricted'.

Comment: Oh god, you didn't get my mind. In fact, you can get 1000 uids at a time by adding "limit=1000" field. In my case, if you use "restricted" uid to get users information, you just get the basic info, but if you use "reality" uid, you can get more infomations about that user (Ex: email, username,...). That's the reason I want to have a real UID.

Comment: I don't think emails are public on Facebook unless the person set it to public. If they're not public, you can't get it, and that's intentional. What information do you need specifically?

Comment: edit: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user use this for profile information for each account. again, you can only see what the user set as "public".